# livereload with visual studio cordova

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, livereload, taco

I would like to use livereload within my Visual Studio Cordova project. Online there is mention of using this with the TACO CLI:
http://taco.tools/docs/run.html#link-4

However, I'm confused on whether the Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova add-on even uses the TACO CLI. I'm ok with using gulp-livereload but was wondering if there was any built-in way or a way to add --livereload if Visual Studio was using the TACO CLI. I appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 1):

The Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova internally uses a build script similar to the TACO CLI, but still different. Unfortunately, the live reload support isn't included in that.

When you work with the Ripple Emulator in Visual Studio, there is a simple live reload mode that will reload your app in the browser when files are changed in the project. It's not the same level of detail as the TACO CLI live-reload, though.